# How to display data based upon dates?

Tags: c#, sql

In my database there is a table named `talltree_master`. I want to display only those records(`tree_no field`) that were not emasculated from beginning. `dtlastemas` field keeps track of date of emasculation and `talltree_id` is the primary key of the table `talltree_master`.
For ex. Consider the following data

```
tree_no | talltree_id |dtlastemas

1       |      1      |    2008-01-09                 
2       |      2      |                 
3       |      3      |    2010-05-06
4       |      4      |                       
1       |      5      |               
5       |      6      |    2001-02-06
2       |      7      |    2009-05-03                   
3       |      8      |    2010-01-01           
6       |      9      |
```

NOTE: Blank means that particular tree has not been emasculated when the emasculation was done.
I want to display is only tree_no 4 and 6 because these are the only trees that has not been emasculated from the beginning where as tree_no 1 and 2 has been emasculated before.
but the below query displays `tree_no` 1,2,4 and 6. how can i modify where condition so that I'll get the correct output.

```
string query = "select tree_no from talltree_master";
       query += " where dtlastemas is NULL";
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html Reading this should get you want you want I guess

Comment: If that is in fact your data, your query doesn't match up with your sample.  Are the values in that table in fact NULL or are they empty strings or both?  This would make a difference in the query you would need.

Comment: @Matt: true, but that's not the question. That's simply visualization on stackoverflow...

Comment: What datatype is dtlastemas?

Comment: What is your DBMS? sql-server, mysql?

Comment: @BobClaerhout hence the garbage in garbage out responses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want those records where `dtlastemas` is null which never had a `dtlastemas` that wasn't null. Something like this:

```
select tree_no
from talltree_master o
where o.dtlastemas is null
    and not exists (
        select *
        from talltree_master i
        where i.tree_no = o.tree_no
              and dtlastemas is not null)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/371db/6

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tree_no, MAX(dtlastemas)
FROM talltree_master
WHERE MAX(dtlastemas) IS NULL
GROUP BY tree_no
```